# what does reactive power mean here?

Tags: power-supply, switches, power-electronics

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcV19A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

assuming this circuit is run for 5 seconds period, the switch is closed for 1 second starting at t=3s

we can calculate average power as average  = 1.8 W
but apparent power S = Vrms * Irms = 4.023 VA
and the difference will be the reactive power which is >0, right?
what does this reactive power mean? in rl or rc circuit it's the powered stored in inductor or capacitor but switch cannot store power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not seeing any reactive power there, that would require and inductor or capacitor.

During the 1 second the switch is closed current is 3V/1 ohm = 3A, and power is 9W giving a total energy expended of 9W * 1s = 9 joules, the rest of the time there is no power dissipated, so the average is indeed 1.8W integrated over 5 seconds, but I do not see where you get ~4VA from?

RMS current is (4 * 0^2 + 1 * 3^2)/5 = 1.34V, and because of the 1 ohm resistor RMS current must be 1.34A. 
1.34V * 1.34A  = 1.8W * 5s = 9 joules.

Comment: it's the apparent power (S) and S=V rms * I rms=4.023 VA

Comment: actually i am asking about the physical meaning of the reactive power here, which is the imaginary component from S= Q J + P

Comment: Vrms * Irms does NOT equal 4.023VA! Vrms is 1.34V measured at the resistor and Irms is 1.34A, giving 1.8VA, and 1.8W because a resistor has a power factor of 1.0. If you consider things between the switch and the power supply, then Vrms is clearly 3V, but IRms is now 0.6A  (root 3^2)/5 again giving 1.8W average, and 9J over the 5s integration time.

Comment: Note my square roots in my original answer seem to be AWOL, but in that case it should be effectively root (9/5) as opposed to root (9)/5, the difference is in where you measure. In no case is reactive power in any way involved.

Comment: good, but dealing with switch and resistor as a single device and measuring V across its terminal then Vrms = 3V and I rms=1.34A

Comment: Vrms does equal 3V, but Irms does NOT equal 1.34A.... You have 3A for 1 second and nothing for four, so Sqrt (3^2 * 1 + 0^2 *4) / 5 = sqrt (9)/5 = 0.6A... The difference is that in one case you are looking at the resistor with 1.34V RMS integrated over 5 seconds, and an RMS current of 1.34A over that 5 seconds, where in the second case you have 3VRMS, but the current is now only drawn for 1 second in 5, not the same situation.

Comment: yes I am looking at that second case (current is drawn for 1 second with const voltage 3V) so what is the difference between apparent power and real power then?

Comment: No difference here, apparent and real power are different only in an AC system having non linear or reactive components. In a DC system you can talk about peak average and RMS voltages and currents and peak and mean power (There is no such thing as RMS power, the concept is not physically meaningful).